# equation alignment problem in two column in latex

Tags: equations, two-column, arrays

I want to shift both the matrices in second row to left, so that equation no. could come properly, Please Somebody Help??? Image is also attached

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.45}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\left (\begin{array}{c} A_L \\ B_L \end{array}\right) = \left
(\begin{array}{cc} f^{-1} & f \\ ik_L f^{-1} &-ik_L f \end{array}
 \right)^{-1} \left (\begin{array}{cc} u_1 & v_1 \\ u'_1 & v'_1  
\end{array} \right)  \left ( \begin{array}{cc} u_2 & v_2 \\ u'_2  & 
v'_2 \end{array} \right)^{-1} \nonumber \\   \left    
\begin{array}{cc} g & g^{-1} \\ ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1}
\\ ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1} \end{array} \right) \left
(\begin{array}{c} A_R \\ B_R \end{array}\right),
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean with "properly"?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but don't load `epsfig`. It has been deprecated for about 25 years. Use `graphicx` if you need to import images.

Comment: You shouldn't use `eqnarray`. It gives bad spacing at thje alignment point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided having many errors, also please avoid to use `eqnarray`, instead of this, use `align` environment, below code may help you to meet your requirement:

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.45}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
A_L \\ B_L
\end{array}
\right) &= \left(
\begin{array}{cc} f^{-1} & f \\ ik_L f^{-1} &-ik_L f \end{array}
 \right)^{-1} \left(\begin{array}{cc}
u_1 & v_1 \\ u'_1 & v'_1  
\end{array} \right)  \left(
\begin{array}{cc} u_2 & v_2 \\ u'_2  & 
v'_2 \end{array} \right)^{-1} \nonumber \\   
&\quad\left(\begin{array}{cc} g & g^{-1} \\ ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1}
\\ ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1} \end{array} \right) \left
(\begin{array}{c} A_R \\ B_R \end{array}\right),
\end{align}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the features of the `amsmath` package, which you have already loaded.

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\begin{pmatrix} 
A_L \\ B_L     
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 f^{-1} & f \\   
ik_L f^{-1} &-ik_L f  
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}  
\begin{pmatrix}   
u_1 & v_1 \\       
u'_1 & v'_1 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  
 u_2 & v_2 \\ 
u'_2  & v'_2   
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\                                  
\begin{pmatrix}   
 g & g^{-1} \\ 
ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1} \\                            
ik_{R} g &-ik_{R} g^{-1}                              
\end{pmatrix}   
\begin{pmatrix}  
 A_R \\ B_R   
\end{pmatrix}  
\end{multline}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: @ mady yuvi , thanks guys, really very helpful :)